# How to run a gms model from API Java in Gams and set a folder with data in files

Tags: java, gams-math

I'm trying to execute a GMS model in GAMS through the API Java. When I execute that model directly from Gams Studio, it works perfectly. But when I run the model  through the API I obtain a lot of errors.
I have searched and I think I need to add input data to the job or workspace(I don't know what of them need to know the input data). I have a folder where I have a lot of files with data and those files are processed from GAMS Studio when I run the GMS model.

[image]

I believe I need to add these files in Java Api too, but I don't know how to add a folder or if I need to add one by one and how to do it.

My code is simple:

```
        GAMSWorkspace workspace = new GAMSWorkspace();
        workspace.setDebugLevel(DebugLevel.KEEP_FILES);
        GAMSJob jobGams = workspace.addJobFromFile("fileModelGms");
        jobGams.run();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with Lutz's user helper. I needed to Include a dir with input that model uses.

This is my code commented line per line to understand how API Gams works. I used a specific workspace too because API creates a folder in temps file when you run a new Job. I did use for a database GDX too to run my model.

```
//specific workspace information is created example: C:/Desktop/Workspace
GAMSWorkspaceInfo workspaceInfo = new GAMSWorkspaceInfo();
workspaceInfo.setWorkingDirectory("specificPathWorkspace");
//A new workspace is created with workspaceInfo.
GAMSWorkspace workspace = new GAMSWorkspace(workspaceInfo);
workspace.setDebugLevel(DebugLevel.KEEP_FILES);
//Options where you're going to set input file data.
GAMSOptions options = workspace.addOptions();
//Set path with input Data example: C:/Desktop/InputDate
options.IDir.add("PathWithInputData");
//Using a database where is data to be processed example: db.gdx
GAMSDatabase gdxdb = workspace.addDatabaseFromGDX("db.gdx");
// Creating a JOB to execute the model.
GAMSJob jobGams = workspace.addJobFromFile(entradasModeloGamsDTO.getPathModeloGams());
//Running model
jobGams.run(options,gdxdb);
```